# delete number and special charter from file

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to use some command in linux that can delete number from file.

```
01 - Lukas Graham - 7 Years [OFFICIAL MUSIC VIDEO]
02 - Prince Royce - La Carretera (Official Video)
```

result

```
Lukas Graham - 7 Years
Prince Royce - La Carretera
```

Answer (score 2):

With **`sed`**:

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9]+ - |[([].+$//g' file
```

The output:

```
Lukas Graham - 7 Years
Prince Royce - La Carretera
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may also help you on same:

```
awk '{sub(/[^a-zA-Z]*/,"");sub(/ [[(].*/,"");print}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Lukas Graham - 7 Years
Prince Royce - La Carretera
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here:

```
awk '{
sub(/[^a-zA-Z]*/,"");  ##Subsituting by using sub keyword of awk everything from starting to till first occurence of any alphabet comes with NULL in current line.
sub(/ [[(].*/,"");     ##Subsituting from space either [ or ( to till last as per OP request with NULL in current line.
print                  ##Printing the current line now.
}
' file                 ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: $ sed -E 's/^[0-9]+ - |[([].+$//g' 01 - Prince Royce  - _Las Cosas Pequeñas_ [Audio].mp3
sed: can't read 01: No such file or directory

Comment: I need to do for 200 song to change it

Comment: @sundrys1, it worked fine for me. Could you please confirm if your Input_file is same as shown sample. Or check `cat -v Input_file` to cross check if you have carriage returns or not, please confirm once.

Comment: $ cat -v 01 - Prince Royce  - _Las Cosas Pequeñas_ [Audio].mp3
cat: 01: No such file or directory
when I use tab I get this

Comment: $ cat 01\ -\ Prince\ Royce\ \ -\ _Las\ Cosas\ Pequeñas_\ \[Audio\].mp3

Comment: this problem with space

Comment: @sundrys1, you could do by `cat -v "your file" in case your file has spaces on it. and Use back ticks for putting codes into CODE TAGS.

Comment: $ sed -E 's/^[0-9]+ - |[([].+$//g' "01 - Prince Royce - Las Cosas Pequeñas [Audio].mp3"
sed: can't read 01 - Prince Royce - Las Cosas Pequeñas [Audio].mp3: No such file or directory

$ cat -v "01 - Prince Royce  - _Las Cosas Pequeñas_ [Audio].mp3"
ID3^D^@^@^@^@^A^_TALB^@^@^@     ^@^@^CBachata^@TIT2^@^@^@/^@^@^CPrince Royce  - "Las Cosas PequeM-CM-1as" [Audio]^

$ ls
'01 - Prince Royce  - _Las Cosas Pequeñas_ [Audio].mp3'

when I use tab key I see this 

$ cat 01\ -\ Prince\ Royce\ \ -\ _Las\ Cosas\ Pequeñas_\ \[Audio\].mp3

Comment: @sundrys1, sorry not clear still, please update your post with samples in  CODE TAGS

Comment: http://217.195.175.87:8080/share.cgi?ssid=08NJBNi here is the folder with song from which I want to delete number before song can you have a look please  ?